# Allow specific user permission to read/write my folder

Tags: linux, unix, permissions, chmod, chown

I have a folder `/home/samantha/folder` that I want to share with the user `tom`. He can read/write the folder. How do I do that?

`chown` wouldn't do it because I still want to be able to be the owner of the folder. I don't see how to do this with `chmod` either.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If you are using **Linux** with a relatively modern filesystem (ext3/ext4, btrfs, ntfs), this can be done with [**POSIX ACLs**](http://www.suse.de/~agruen/acl/linux-acls/online/):

1. Enable ACLs for the filesystem. This is only necessary for ext3 and ext4 on kernels older than 2.6.38. All other filesystems that support ACLs enable them automatically.

   ```
   mount -o remount,acl /
   tune2fs -o acl /dev/<partition>
   ```
2. Give `tom` access to the folder:

   ```
   setfacl -m user:tom:rwx /home/samantha/folder
   ```

---

If the OS or the filesystem does not support ACLs, another way is to **use groups.**

1. Create a group.

   - Some Linux distributions create a separate group for each user: `tom` would automatically be in a group also named `tom`.
   - If not, create a group. This should work on Linux...

     ```
     groupadd tom
     gpasswd -a tom tom
     ```

     ...and this - on BSD:

     ```
     groupadd tom
     usermod -G tom tom
     ```
2. `chgrp` the directory to that group, and give permissions with `chmod`:

   ```
    chgrp tom /home/samantha/folder
    chmod g+rwx /home/samantha/folder
   ```

Comment: FWIW, the OP added an additional answer instead of commenting. He/she has a question about your solution. Thanks.

Comment: And tom will also need execute permission on /home/samantha to be able to reach /home/samantha/folder.

Answer (score 2):

Add both users to a common group. Make that group own the directory, and assign group permissions as needed.

- [How to create a new Group on UNIX](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/groupadd.htm)
- [How To Add a User to a Group on UNIX](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-add-user-to-group)
- [Group Permissions for Files and Directories](http://www.udel.edu/it/help/unix/unixgroups.html#permission)