# Folder User Permissions on Linux

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [allow specific user permission to read/write my folder](https://superuser.com/questions/235297/allow-specific-user-permission-to-read-write-my-folder)

I have a folder called `/TAR/Sketch`

I added a new user, named `Snoopy`, I want to grant this user the ability to add files & directories to this folder which is under the group `Sketches` and the owner is me.

How can I accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the user to the "Sketches" group and set the folder as group-writable.