# How to add user to folder permissions?

Tags: linux, permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow specific user permission to read/write my folder](https://superuser.com/questions/235297/allow-specific-user-permission-to-read-write-my-folder)

I have a folder, `/home/oliver`, which is the home directory for my user `oliver`. I am going to set up a file server and would like the `apache` user to be able to read from this folder.

At the moment the `apache` user can’t see this folder at all.

What are the commands to do this? I’m new to Linux so I don’t understand the concept of groups etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a group oliver which is the current group of your home folder. You need to add apache to this group. Use `usermod -a -G oliver apache` as root (probably using `sudo`) to add the apache user to the group oliver. You will need to restart apache (or your machine) to apply the change.

After this you can control the permissions with the group permission. Write access isn't usually given by default to other group members, so you may want to run `chmod -R g+w /home/oliver`. That adds write permission (+w) for other members of the group (g), recursively (-R). You own the folder, so you do not need sudo for that.

Keep in mind that apache may not run under the username apache. It may be something such as `www`, `www-data`, or `webuser`. Either check `top`/`ps` to see what it is running as, or run `cat /etc/passwd` and see which user looks like apache uses it. More specific instruction would require what distribution you are running and what version.

Comment: Thanks for explaining how the groups work. Is it safe to assume that we can give `apache` rights to everything owned by the `oliver` group, as I only want the home directory?

Comment: Well, in general the only things owned by the `oliver` group are in your home directory, since that's where 'your' things are.

Of course, you could make a folder owned by apache and add yourself to its group so you can edit.

Answer (score 1):

If you have ACL's enabled, then a quick way would be to set an ACL for Apache, as in:

```
setfacl -m u:apache:r /home/oliver
```

For additional details `man setfacl` and `man getfacl`.

Comment: I don’t have ACL enabled and I’m not sure how to enable it (running Centos 5.8).