# How to give user rwx access to another user?

Tags: linux, permissions

How can I give userA access to all files created by userB / userC, including rwx permission?

Is there a way to do this without giving root access?

Adding to same group won't work because not all the files will have group access.
And setfacl can be executed on current files but does not apply to future files created.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/235297/allow-specific-user-permission-to-read-write-my-folder

Comment: I don't want to share just a single folder, but everything by that user

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ACLs.

```
setfacl -R -m user:User:rwX /some/path
```

*(note upper-case `X`)*

`setfacl` *does* apply to future files created, if you also set the "default" ACL:

```
setfacl -R -m default:user:UserA:rwx /some/path
```

Comment: is the executable permission for default intentionally lowercase?

Comment: @Richard: When setting default permissions, both `X` and `x` appear to have the same effect.

Answer (score 3):

You can give userA sudo rights to become userB / userC. Would that do it?

Comment: need to have same permission as if that user, so sudo would not work