# FTP user permissions Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, ftp, read-write

I have a question about ftp rights on Ubuntu. 
I want to give a user only permission on 2 or more directories. The user may only see this directories. What file do I need to edit and what do I need to edit.

Comment: Try this one: http://superuser.com/questions/235297/allow-specific-user-permission-to-read-write-my-folder